# How to access main.js file n angular project on deployment over cloud

Tags: angular, single-page-application, micro-frontend

I am working  on an angular project for this single spa micro frontend application,

```
{
      "imports": {
        "app1": "http://localhost:4201/main.js",
       "login": "http://localhost:4204/main.js",
      }
}
```

I have deployed my app1 on cloud but on every build a different main.js like this mainedsf24r43.js gets generated, hence I am getting an error :

open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/main.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /main.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:4200/"

Any solution on how we can overcome this issue.

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to accomplish, but anyway, to remove hashing, in angular.json set "outputHashing" to "none"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli, simply set `projects.<projectName>.architect.build.configurations.production.outputHashing` to "none" in your angular.json